# Virtual Server 2005 R2 - Fixed Disk does deleting files allow space to be reused

Tags: windows, hyper-v

OS: Windows 2003 SP2
VS: 2005 R2

I'm aware that if you use a dynamic disk, to recover space (shrink the disk) you need to run through the compact routine. My question is if I convert my dynamic disk to a fixed disk size, if I delete files within a fixed disk is the space re-useable for new files? No where on a google search, microsoft or wiki seem to even mention what occurs.

Regards

Morpheus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fixed size disk is essentially a simple hard disk image. Space will be re-used as it would on a real hard disk. You won't be able to tell that it's happening from the host machine as the disk size would remain the same. It's down to the file system in the guest operating system.